# Transfer Data between 3 UITabBar with custom cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tabs, uitabbar

I have read a lot of similar topics questions but this one is different. 
I have 3 tab bar controller and each tab bar controller have many custom static cells. Each cell has data like UISwitch, UIDatePicker, UITextField. I would like all of that data to get transferred from tab 1 to tab 3 and tab 2 to tab 3, so I can use it to calculate information and display it on tab 3. 
I have tried few things, but I am having problems setting up the segue and getting data from many custom cells into the tab1 controller and send it to tab 3 controller and also the same with tab2 to tab 3. I am having problem because Tab1 have 11 different custom cell classes, where all the data is being set. 
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a model appropriate for you data.

Make variables of that model in your ViewController or custom cell classes (hard to tell without more information what is the best place to create them).

Then have the VC update it's cell(s) or let the cell update themselves from that data.